# How to check for Jupyter running notebooks through command line

Tags: shell, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm setting up a cluster for running Jupyter notebook on google cloud platform, but need to automate the cluster shutdown process to save money, interrupting the shutdown script if someone is running something.

How can I check if there is any running notebooks using shell script?

Comment: There's some Python code [here](https://github.com/takluyver/nbmanager/blob/master/nbmanager/api.py) that identifies running notebook servers and kernels. You could adapt that into a script that checks if there are any.

Comment: How about just doing `ps -ef | grep jupyter`?

Comment: thanks @Thomas K, that sure will help me a lot on my next steps.

Comment: @KeithHughitt, haven't thought that, thanks

Comment: If you know the port number, could use `lsof` to check what process is listening to the port. See the full answer on how to use `lsof` [described here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149478/169406)

Comment: How about `jupyter notebook list`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jupyter notebook --help-all` shows a lot of helpful options, but my approach was getting all the sessions from the api by calling: 
`curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" "http://<server>/api/sessions"` and then you can parse this data.
Not sure if that can help you, but give a try!

Comment: I used the solution from @VagnerLucas to make a little alias that makes use of python to pretty print the output.

`alias show_kernels="curl -s -i -H \"Accept: application/json\" \"http://<server>/api/sessions\"|tail -1 |  python -c \"import sys, pprint; pp=pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4);pp.pprint(eval(sys.stdin.readlines()[0]))\""`